# Iterate and update python dictionary not working

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

Trying to iterate through a dictionary and update its values accordingly.  For some reason I cant get it to work.  I created a simple example below.  It saves the last iterated 'id' to both of the key values in the dictionary.

The sample code is:

```
import copy

#####
def setParams(params):
    for key,valuesDict in params.items():
        print(key)
        params[key]['target']['id'] = key

targetDict = {'id':"",'value':0}
myParamsTemplate = {'target':targetDict}
first = copy.copy(myParamsTemplate)
second = copy.copy(myParamsTemplate)


params = {"1":first,"2":second}

print("before:\n",params)

setParams(params)

print("after:\n",params)
```

prints out:

```
before:
 {'1': {'target': {'id': '', 'value': 0}}, '2': {'target': {'id': '', 'value': 0}}}
1
2
after:
 {'1': {'target': {'id': '2', 'value': 0}}, '2': {'target': {'id': '2', 'value': 0}}}
```

The 'id' should be 1 and 2 respectively, yet the result is always '2' for both.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're only doing a shallow copy (which doesn't copy the innermost dictionary). You can easily verify this by printing `params["1"]["target"] is params["2"]["target"]` it should return `True` (which means they are the same object).

You could make it work by using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
first = copy.deepcopy(myParamsTemplate)
second = copy.deepcopy(myParamsTemplate)
```